# How can I format this path to work in a registry key?

Tags: windows, registry, special-characters, registrykey

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\DotR\DotR.exe
```

I know I need to escape the backslashes like `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\DotR\\DotR.exe` but it still doesn't work. Do I need to handle spaces and parens as special characters and if so, how?

Edit with details: I'm running a small console application from the context menu. When I save it to C:\DotR.exe and add to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\DotR\` the value `C:\\DotR.exe %1` it works fine but when I try to make it `C:\\Program Files(x86)\\DotR\DotR.exe %1` I get an error message that says application not found. I want to save it in program files and not C root.

Comment: For paths containing spaces generally you double quote the whole path: `"C:\Program Files(x86)\DotR\DotR.exe" %1`

Comment: I added quotes and it worked. If you make this an answer I'll accept. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to escape the backslashes in the registry value, although you may need to escape them in your source code depending on which language you're using.